# Enabling the dropdown list field only for the rows which has data (not working as expected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am displaying the dynamic JSON data in the html table when user clicks on *`GetData`* button.

When user clicked on *`GetData`* button I'm getting two rows values from the backend which I'm successfully showing in the table. 
Initially when the html table is loaded the first column *`Year`* is disabled and *`Mortgage Type`* column is editable. When user
click on `GetData` button, I'm showing two rows information in the table by disabling the *`Mortgage Type`* column and enabling the
"*`Year`*" column. Issue is **I want to enable *`Year`* `column`** **only for the rows for which I got the information from `backend`**(first two rows in my case).

Below is the sample code I used to enable the Year drop down list for first two rows when user click on *`GetData`* button, but it is enabling for all the rows:

```
$('#loanTable tr ').each(function(){
   for (var i = 0; i < mortageType.length; i++) {
$('td:eq(0) select', this).removeAttr("disabled");//last row enabled
  }
});
```

Demo link : https://plnkr.co/edit/Fon9NDQA0q660wSz0RHv?p=preview

In the above Demo link, when user click on *`GetData`* button, I want to enable the *`Year`* field only for the first two rows for which I got information, the remaining rows should be disabled.

--EDITED--

The below code is failing in one scenario. When i get the null values from backend in any row, i should not enable or disable any fields and highlight the row with red color which is working fine in the demo link shown below.

https://plnkr.co/edit/fDmFtxdxKk8eeswx4lGT?p=preview

But **the same code is failing to enable the Year column** when there are no null values.
Please see the updated plunker without null values, **failing** to enable the first row Year dropdown list field:

https://plnkr.co/edit/7pB8q54JavFlCm5Y8gF8?p=preview

When user click on GetData button, Year dropdown list fields for first two rows should be enabled and should be disabled for the last two rows for which data is not available..

Sample code snippet:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mortageType.length; i++) {
                j = j + 1;
                document.getElementById("mortageType" + j).value = mortageType[i].code;
                document.getElementById("loanNum" + j).innerText = loanNum[i].code;
                document.getElementById("status" + j).innerText = status[i].code;
                //to enable the Year field for the rows we are fetching the data
                 // $(document.getElementById("year" + j)).removeAttr('disabled');
               if(loanNum[i].code == null || mortageType[i].code == null || status[i].code==null ){
                  console.log("row has null value");
                  $('#status' + j).parent().parent().css({'border':'red'});   
                  enablingFlag = false; //If any field value is null make the flag as false
                 }
                 if(enablingFlag){ //enters the if condition if there are no null values 
                   $('#loanTable input, #loanTable select').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                   $(document.getElementById("year" + j)).removeAttr('disabled');
                 }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simplify and get rid of the whole block that iterates and removes the disabled attribute.

You are already iterating.. So make each year select have an id that follows the pattern you are using for the other controls.   `year1, year2, year3, year4`

then on, or around, line 24 of your javascript add this:

`$(document.getElementById("year" + j)).removeAttr('disabled');`

html element ids should be unique anyway so you'd want to fix those year select boxes either way.

Here is a plunker illustrating it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/dBDlBrc3CVPA46aMT6OA?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. With your code, it is enabling Mortgage Type fields for the last two rows which doesn't have data.They should be disabled too. The line of code i used is  $('#loanTable input, #loanTable select').attr("disabled", "disabled"); based on the enabledFlag value shown in my plunker shared in the post.

Comment: I modified the code along with your code https://plnkr.co/edit/PahIADi1ftkYieDQ54Jv?p=preview but the year dropdown for the first row is not enabled..

Comment: sorry, I missed that line where you were disabling things.

try this one: https://plnkr.co/edit/dBDlBrc3CVPA46aMT6OA?p=preview

I disable them all, then process the json and during the json iteration just enable the ones you want enabled.

In your example you re-disable them on each pass through so only the last one ends up being enabled.

Note: that plunkr link is the same as in my "answer" it's just updated code.

Comment: Sorry , missed one scenario. Please see my edited section in the post above. When i get a null value i should not enable the Year field and the fields should be same as before with data loaded and showing the red highlight for the null value row. But again if i get the data succesfully with my modified code, it is failing in one scenario. Please find the plunkers i shared in the edited section above.thanks.